# Check and style the result of form in PHP

Tags: php

I created a form with two input text boxes (first and last name). When the user click on the submit button the result should be replaced all "s" latter with number "5" which I already done, and underline the first "e" if one exists and finally italic the last 3 characters only if they are "son".
Thank you for helping.

```
<?php
 $_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
 $fullname = $_POST['firstname'] . ' ' . $_POST['lastname'];
 echo str_replace("s", "5", $fullname);
?>

<form action="form.php" method="post"> 
First Name: 
<input type="text" name="firstname"><br> 
Last Name: 
<input type="text" name="lastname"><br> <input type="submit"> 
</form>
```

Comment: Can you paste all your code so that I can run it? And to be clear, your question is how do you underline e and set the last 3 characters to italic of they are son?

Comment: my tip would be `strpos()`

Comment: Thank you @SuperKevin !
If the last name for example "Jackson" then the result should be "Jack_son_"
    (ahmedbagaber.onlinewebshop.net/dps3.php)

Comment: I am asking if you could post your HTML form so that I can just copy and paste it to my editor. I am lazy and don't want to build it out =]

Comment: `<form action="form.php" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a clean solution to this problem using recursion and without relying on loops.

The form is similar to what you previously had. I did changed the action param.

```
<form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post"> <!-- You need update the action to hit your script -->
    First Name:
    <input type="text" name="firstname">
    Last Name:
    <input type="text" name="lastname">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here's where all the "magic" happens.

```
    <?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $fullname = $_POST['firstname'] . ' ' . $_POST['lastname'];
        echo parse($fullname);
    }

    function parse($name) {
        if (strpos(strtolower($name), "son")) {
            $name = italize($name, strlen($name));
        }
        $name = transform($name);
        $name = underline($name);
        return $name;
    }

    function underline($name) {
        $found = strpos(strtolower($name), 'e');
        if ($found !== false) {
            return substr_replace($name, '<u>e</u>', $found, 1);
        }
        return $name;
    }

    function transform($name) {
        return str_replace("s", "5", strtolower($name));
    }

    function italize($name, $index, $string = "") {
        if ($index === 0) { return $string; }

        if ($index === 3) {
            $string .= "<i>";
        }

        $string .= $name[strlen($name) - $index];

        if ($index === 1) {
            $string .= "</i>";
        }

        return italize($name,$index-1,$string);
    }
?>
```

**Edit**

Changed my answer to not rely on loops at all. I used recursion to iterate through the `$fullname` and italize it if needed.